How to make TypeScript enum-like type where multiple values map to the same key
I am trying to take a part of the codebase that was using type string and convert it to an enum-like type, using TypeScript. The problem is that in some places the string values are slightly different. Rather than make two nearly-identical enum-like types, is there a way to make a single type where multiple values match to the same key?
My attempt looks like this (which does not work):
const STATUS = {
    CREATED: "CREATED",
    PICKED_UP: "PICKED UP" | "PICKED_UP",
    DELIVERED: "DELIVERED" | "DEL"
} as const
type ObjectValues<T> = T[keyof T];
type Status = ObjectValues<typeof STATUS>;

I am looking for a solution that would do this:
console.log(STATUS.PICKED_UP === "PICKED UP" && STATUS.PICKED_UP === "PICKED_UP") //should be true
doThingWithStatus("PICKED_UP") //should be ok, assuming function expects a type Status input

Thanks, folks!

How would you expect STATUS.PICKED_UP === "PICKED UP" and STATUS.PICKED_UP === "PICKED_UP" to be true? That's impossible, it's either one string or it's the other.  Maybe you want STATUS's members to be collections of strings? Like, you could make them arrays as shown in this playground link. Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

Oh, yeah. You're right. That doesn't make any sense. One of those things that seems really silly now that you pointed it out
I guess what I ultimately need is for both versions to be accepted by type Status, which I do easily...
I think you solution is a pretty good one. If you want to write it up, I'll accept it.

As stated, no, it is not possible to do what you're asking. Surely you can't have both STATUS.PICKED_UP === "PICKED UP" be true and STATUS.PICKED_UP === "PICKED_UP" be true, when "PICKED UP" === "PICKED_UP" is false.  STATUS.PICKED_UP is some value, and that value can be either or neither of those strings, but it cannot be both of those strings.  (And this is probably why you're having trouble writing a value like "PICKED UP" | "PICKED_UP". Anyway, that's the bitwise OR operator and doesn't act on strings. And there is no operator that combines two strings into a single string that somehow equals both of them.)

Instead it seems like you should refactor so you're mapping members of STATUS to collections of strings. For example, you could use arrays as in
const STATUS = {
  CREATED: ["CREATED"],
  PICKED_UP: ["PICKED UP", "PICKED_UP"],
  DELIVERED: ["DELIVERED", "DEL"]
} as const;

Then Status is the union of the elements of ObjectValues<typeof STATUS>:
type Status = ObjectValues<typeof STATUS>[number];
// type Status = "CREATED" | "PICKED UP" | "PICKED_UP" | "DELIVERED" | "DEL"

And your check would be whether the member of STATUS includes one of the strings in its collection:
console.log(
  STATUS.PICKED_UP.includes("PICKED UP") &&
  STATUS.PICKED_UP.includes("PICKED_UP")
); // true


You don't need to use arrays; you could use Sets, or objects with the strings as the keys.

You could even just reverse your STATUS object so that the keys and values are switched, since objects allow properties with different keys to have the same value, but not vice versa (and I don't see you suggesting that, for example, "DEL" appear in both STATUS.DELIVERED and, say, STATUS.DELETED. Presumably you have a many-to-one or one-to-many relationship in mind, not a many-to-many):
const STATUS_REV = {
  CREATED: "CREATED",
  PICKED_UP: "PICKED_UP",
  "PICKED UP": "PICKED_UP",
  DELIVERED: "DELIVERED",
  DEL: "DELIVERED"
} as const

Then Status is the union of the keys of STATUS_REV
type Status = keyof typeof STATUS_REV;
// type Status = "CREATED" | "PICKED UP" | "PICKED_UP" | "DELIVERED" | "DEL"

And your check would be whether the former key is the value of either the "PICKED UP" or the "PICKED_UP" property of STATUS_REV:
console.log(
  "PICKED_UP" === STATUS_REV["PICKED UP"] && 
  "PICKED_UP" === STATUS_REV["PICKED_UP"]
); // true

Playground link to code
